# CSS - Disabling double-click auto selection in chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML/CSS right now, so I did this little cookie-clicker lookalike for fun : http://jsfiddle.net/Zerh/6kb87sp9/

My problem is : if I click too fast on any button (double click) it highlights a selection.
I used the following CSS for hiding the highlight :

```
::selection {
   background: transparent;
}
::-moz-selection {
   background: transparent;
}
```

It seems to work on Firefox/Edge but I can't get it to work on Chrome.

I found this old topic : [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting), but it's 6 years old and doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will disable on any element

```
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

I think this will solve your problem you just need to add the class "noselect" to the element you want

Comment: Do not forget to mark as answered to help other users ;)